# Problem in loading the package TiberCreek.Toolkit.Common v 3.2.0.12

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a already developed project in Asp.net, I am stuck with an issue which is to resolve the dependency issue of TiberCreek.Toolkit.Common v 3.2.0.12 , it is there in the dependencies but it is not able to locate in the C:/ drive. It is  not even in the NugetPackage manager, it says " Not available in this source" . Please help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJSUY.png

Comment: Are you sure there's still a NuGet package for TiberCreek?  I don't see anything here: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=tibercreek

Comment: actually project name is TiberCreek but the package is "Toolkit.common v 3.2.0.12"

Comment: I think `TiberCreek.Toolkit.Common` nuget package is your own created nuget package rather than on the `nuget.rog` or other feed, so when you use it, you should publish it on the [package source path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources).

Comment: I found that the project was using it's own private package, and it was not in the c folder. I just copied the package from original source and pasted it in c drive. That way it is solved now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @prashant, since the workaround helps you handle the issue and I have added your detailed info into the answer. You can check it.

Comment: @prashant, since my answer helps you handle this issue, why don't you mark it? And it will help other community members search and handle similar issues and also help us create a good community atmosphere. If you have a better workaround,please add a new answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem in loading the package TiberCreek.Toolkit.Common v 3.2.0.12

The package called `TiberCreek.Toolkit.Common` is not available on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/). I assume the package `TiberCreek.Toolkit.Common` is created by your team and it is your own package.

So you should contact with your team about the issueand make sure that they did not abandon the version `3.2.0.12` of the package on your **private nuget feed**.

**Suggestion**

**1)** You should check every [nuget package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources) and make sure you have published the version `v 3.2.0.12` of the package on your nuget package source.

You should contact with the team and let them publish that version of package into the nuget feed.

**2)** If you have the version `3.2.0.12` nuget source package through some means, you can copy the `TiberCreek.Toolkit.Common 3.2.0.12.nupkg` file into  your local path `C:\Dev\Build\Nuget\packages`, and then nuget will find the package and restore it successfully.

===========

**Update**

From **prashant's** description, it is a private nuget package which belongs to them.

Just find the source nuget package and then copy it into the local path c disk which fixes the issue.

Comment: @prashant, thanks for your feedback. Just as I assume that, it is your own private nuget  package.So it cannot be got on `nuget.org`. One solution is that you should find the source package `TiberCreek.Toolkit.Common 3.2.0.12.nupkg` and then copy it into your local nuget source path.